# Adding a stylesheet declaration in my xml using Xerces-C

Tags: c++, xml, stylesheet, xerces-c, xml-declaration

I have an application in c++ using Xerces-C as main xml manipulation library.

I have my DOMDocument* and my parser and I want to set declarations.

I do the following:

```
parser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
parser->setDoSchema(false);
parser->setLoadExternalDTD(false);
```

I want to add:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my_xslt.xsl"?>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the createProcessingInstruction on the DOMDocument
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMDocument.html#ce898787ba20c00c85be63f28a358507

Once you've created it, append it to the DocumentElement.

Comment: Well I tried it and somehow worked but I found a better solution, in my context, using another fuctionality... writing the declaration in the string to parse... the written declaration is parsed too... however thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for doing this:

```
xercesc::DomDocument *doc;
// ... (initialize doc in some way)
auto root = doc->getDocumentElement();
auto stylesheet = doc->createProcessingInstruction
  (X("xml-stylesheet"), X("type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"custom.xsl\""));
doc->insertBefore(stylesheet, root);
```

This way, the stylesheet information appears in the prolog of the document, which is the typical place for it. `X()` is some function that encodes a C-style string as a Xerces-compatible `XMLCh`-string.